# Error al implementar un puntero a array en C++

Tags: c++, array, punteros

estoy haciendo ejercicios de programación de la universidad y estoy con este:

> Escribir un programa en el que se defina un tipo, PunteroArray, puntero a ARRAY de mil posiciones cuyo dato
>   almacenado sea un puntero a int:
>
>  Declarar y escribir un procedimiento, crearArray, al que le pasemos
>   una variable de PunteroArray y devuelva la memoria dinámica necesaria
>   para almacenar 1000 enteros.
>
>  Declarar y escribir el código de un procedimiento que inicialice,
>   inicializarArray, una variable PunteroArray, que se ha pasado ya a
>   crearArray (tiene la memoria dinámica necesaria) con valores
>   consecutivos de 1 a 1000.
>
>  Declarar y escribir el código de un procedimiento, escribirArray,
>   que dada una variable de PunteroArray, y después de llamara a
>   crearArray y a inicializarArray, escriba sus valores.
>
>  Escribir un programa principal que llame a crearArray,
>   inicializarArray y escribirArray en secuencia.

Tengo este código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cabecera.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    PunteroArray array;

    return 0;
}

void crearArray(PunteroArray& ar)
{
    PunteroArray* ar = new PunteroArray;
}

void inicializarArray(PunteroArray& ar)
{
    for(int i=0; i<1000;i++)
    {
        ar.a[i]=i++;
    }
}
```

Al hacer build me da el siguiente error:

> declaration of 'PunteroArray* ar' shadows a parameter
>        PunteroArray* ar = new PunteroArray;

Tengo entendido que significa que estoy reutilizando la variable ar, pero entonces, **¿como le asigno memoria dinámica de otra manera a mi array?**

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: `... que se defina un tipo, PunteroArray, puntero a ARRAY de mil posiciones cuyo dato almacenado sea un puntero a int:` 
¿Un puntero a un array de 1000 punteros a int? 
Eso sería `typedef int*(*PunteroArray)[1000];`

Comment: no, los struct ya me vienen dados por el ejercicio, no puedo modificarlos.

Comment: Este ejercicio carece de sentido. ¿Qué universidad te está pidiendo algo tan disparatado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tratando de ajustarme a la primera definición:

> ... que se defina un tipo, PunteroArray, puntero a ARRAY de mil posiciones
>   cuyo dato almacenado sea un puntero a int:

mi interpretación de eso es:

```
struct ARRAY {
    ARRAY() : n(new int) {}
    ~ARRAY() { delete n; }
    int* n;
};

// tipo PunteroArray, puntero a ARRAY de mil posiciones 
// cuyo dato almacenado sea un puntero a int:
typedef ARRAY(* PunteroArray)[1000];
```

donde el tipo `PunteroArray` es un puntero a un array de 1000 objetos de tipo ARRAY (que cada uno de ellos almacena un puntero a int).

Entonces, con esa definición particular (¿caprichosa?), una posible solución es:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ARRAY {
    ARRAY() : n(new int) {}
    ~ARRAY() { delete n; }
    int* n;
};

// tipo PunteroArray, puntero a ARRAY de mil posiciones 
// cuyo dato almacenado sea un puntero a int.
typedef ARRAY(* PunteroArray)[1000]; 


// recibe una variable de tipo PunteroArray sin inicialzar y
// devuelve la dirección de memoria libre reservada para 1000 ARRAYs
PunteroArray crearArray(PunteroArray& p)
{
    p = (PunteroArray)new ARRAY[1000];
    return p;
}

// asigna valores consecutivos de 1 a 1000
// a las direcciones apuntadas por los miembros n de cada p
void inicializarArray(PunteroArray p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        *((ARRAY*)&p[0])[i].n = i+1;
}

// crea el puntero a array,
// lo inicializa y
// muestra en consola los elementos del array
void escribirArray(PunteroArray& p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        std::cout << *((ARRAY*)&p[0])[i].n << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    PunteroArray p = nullptr;
    crearArray(p);
    inicializarArray(p);
    escribirArray(p);
    delete [] p;
}
```

Comment: Supongo que el enunciado debe tener algo incorrecto, pero implementaré tu código y lo estudiare detenidamente porque es interesante, me parece rebuscado según la interpretación literal. Gracias gracias que ando flojo en estructura de datos y gente asi me salva la asignatura, más por lo que aprendo corrigiendo que leyendo lo de mi profesor.

Comment: Mezclar juntos un analista funcional, un arquitecto, un diseñador y un programador, poner todo eso en una bolsa y hacerle un nudo firme, bien firme, y volver después de una semana a ver si ha sobrevivido alguno.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a los que hayan estado mirando y pensando pero publico mi solución.
He estado bastante ciego, era un simple error.

Código corregido:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cabecera.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    PunteroArray array;

    crearArray(array);

    inicializarArray(array);

    escribirArray(array);

    return 0;
}

void crearArray(PunteroArray& ar)
{
    PunteroArray* p = new PunteroArray; //aquí estaba el error
    p=&ar;//asignar la direccion de nuestra estructura a la memdin
}

void inicializarArray(PunteroArray& ar)
{
    for(int i=0; i<1000;i++)
    {
        ar.a[i]=i+1;
    }
}

void escribirArray(PunteroArray &ar)
{
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        cout<<"dato:"<<ar.a[i]<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Simplemente había que asignar memoria dinamica con otro puntero de tipo PunteroArray, y asignar a esta la dirección de nuestra estructura Puntero a array.

Aquí la cabecera con la declaración del struct:

```
#ifndef CABECERA_H
#define CABECERA_H

struct PunteroArray
{
    int a[1000];
    int* b=a; //no llego a entender la necesidad de este puntero si no he llegado a usarlo para resolver el problema
};

void crearArray(PunteroArray& ar);

void inicializarArray(PunteroArray& ar);

void escribirArray(PunteroArray& ar);


#endif // CABECERA_H
```

Gracias.

Comment: tu `crearArray()` no está bien, y tampoco responde a " y devuelva la memoria dinámica necesaria para almacenar 1000 enteros"

Comment: @asdasdasd En que está mal? aparte de lo de devolver la memoria din.

Comment: Por un lado, no puedo decir que entiendo la definición de "PunteroArray" que te han dado (yo pediría que la aclaren o que la corrijan) pero estoy seguro de que la que has puesto no es un `puntero a ARRAY de mil posiciones cuyo dato almacenado sea un puntero a int:` Y con respecto a `crearArray()`, debería devolver `la memoria dinámica necesaria para almacenar 1000 enteros`(que supongo que debe ser un puntero a int, pero también preguntaría). Me da la impresión de que tu profesor tiene algún tipo de dificultad con el idioma.

Comment: @asdasdasd entiendo por lo que dices que lo que realmente he puesto es un struct de un array de 1000 pos que almacena un puntero a ese array? (tiene que ser con struct no puedo usar typedef).
PD: mi profesor deja mucho que desear, muy a mi pesar.